# What is the Hahn Banach extension of this map?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$f(x,y)=3x$ on $X=${$(x,y): x=y$} is a linear functional on the subspace $X\subset \Bbb R^2$.

Here the norm on $\Bbb R^2 $ is defined as $\|(x,y)\|= |x|+|y|$.
Let $g(x,y)=ax+by$ on $\Bbb R^2$, where $g$ is a Hahn Banach extension of $f$. Then what must $a-b$ be?

I know that if $g$ is restricted to $X$, then $g$ must be equal to $f$ and this implies $a+b=3$. But how do I proceed further?

Comment: What is the norm of $f$? What are the norms of $g\lvert_{\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}}$ and $g\lvert_{\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: norm of should be 3

Comment: @Upstart: The norm of $f$ is ${3 \over 2}$. What is $\|(x,x)\|$?

Comment: i have actually just started this topic so i am a little unsure.$2|x|$

Comment: You have $|f(x,x) | = 3|x| = {3 \over 2} 2 |x| = {3 \over 2} \|(x,x)\|$, from which you can read off the operator norm of $f$.

Comment: You can compute the norm of $g$ in terms of $a,b$. Then you have the additional constraint in $a,b$ that you discovered. Then an 'ah hah' moment :-).